# Flatten/ Concatenate Postgres JSONB array

Tags: postgresql, json, jsonb

I am trying to form a jsonb object (not array) from the table (t1) below

| id | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | hello | world |
| 1 | dns | 192.2.8.0 |
| 1 | people | 1000 |

I have tried

```
SELECT jsonb_agg(('{"' || key || '" : "' || value || '"}')::jsonb) as kv_pair FROM t1 GROUP BY id
```

This yields `[{"hello":"world"}, {"dns":"192.2.8.0"},  {"people":1000}]`

How do I flatten/ concatenate the array so the output is just a single object like so:

```
{"hello":"world" , "dns":"192.2.8.0" ,  "people":1000}
```

It is important that I have a single object for an alembic migration.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

turns out I was overcomplicating things and using the wrong function

```
SELECT id, jsonb_object_agg(key, value) as kv_pair
FROM t1 
GROUP BY id
```